# Problem with positional parameters in JPA native query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to do:

```
String sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE (type like 'B') AND (username like '?1')";
List results = em.createNativeQuery(sql).setParameter(1, username).getResultList();
```

But I get IllegalArgumentException that tells me that the parameter is out of bounds. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There shoudn't be quotes around the parameters. Try this instead:

```
String sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE (type like 'B') AND (username like ?1)";
```

You might also want to double-check that you really mean `type like 'B'` as this probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I think they are 1-based (contrary to logic)

Comment: @Bozho: Sure? *Contrary to JDBC, Hibernate numbers parameters from zero.* http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying-executing

Comment: Ah, correct. I've always used named parameters, so this has eluded me :)

Comment: Hibernate params are 0-based. JPA are 1-based. Your syntax is good for Hibernate but not according to the JPA spec. I'll try your syntax and we'll see in a second.

Comment: What's the problem with "type like 'B'"?

Comment: like matches wildcard patterns. 'B' is a string with no wildcard. use = instead of like

Comment: It was indeed the quotes, thanks - but with the number, so it's "username like ?1".

Answer (score 3):

a) Why would you use native SQL for a simple query like this? Use JPQL.
b) Why use like if you don't use wildcards? Use `=` instead.

```
String jpql =
  "SELECT u.email FROM users u WHERE (u.type = 'B') AND (u.username = '?1')";

List results = 
    em.createQuery(jpql)
      .setParameter(1, username)
      .getResultList();
```

Comment: I don't have an object representation for the users, so especially because it's a simple query I chose Native. I actually have a big DB with lots of entities, all nicely done with JPA, but I have this external DB which I use for 2-3 queries (like this one), so I opted to keep it simple with native queries.