# How to use JPA Prepared statment for Insert query in java

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, prepared-statement, insert-query

I would like to know how to use prepared statement for insert query. Generally for select query I am using in following way.

```
Query query = JPA.em()
    .createNativeQuery("select item_status from item_details where box_id=:boxnumber");
query.setParameter("boxnumber", boxNumber);
```

But when I am using insert query I am unable to use in the above way.

```
Query query = JPA.em()
    .createNativeQuery("insert into item_details values(':item_status')");
query.setParameter("item_status", itemstat);
```

I am getting error like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [item_status]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:368) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
```

please any one help me to sort out this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA/Hibernate Native Queries do not recognize Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144235/jpa-hibernate-native-queries-do-not-recognize-parameters)

Comment: its not similar. My doubt regarding insert query. select query is working perfectly for me. issues is with insert query

Comment: Have you tried to use solutions suggested there? Did they work? If they didn't you might want to specify what exactly didn't work as expected. P.S. is select query also native?

Comment: Hold on a second. You error message says: `could not locate named parameter [boxnumber]` and your query doesn't even have `boxnumber` as a parameter. Are you sure that you posted exactly the problematic query?

Comment: Yes select query also native. Select query is working properly.Also the post you have mentioned not even have one insert example. I tried with some example which are available but its also not working.

Comment: My error message according to above post is could not locate named parameter [item_status]. I have cut shorted my question when I am posting but the error I forgot to change according to question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66760/discussion-between-default-locale-and-kathirvel-appusamy).

Comment: Turns out the actual problem was the quoted query parameter. So, the real duplicate is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144660/problem-with-positional-parameters-in-jpa-native-query)

Answer (score 1):

I could't tested but could you try this;

```
Query query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("insert into item_details(item_status) values(?)") .setParameter(1, itemstat).executeUpdate();
```